# Why do I get so different estimations with glm and glmer?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, poisson-regression

I am using the `glmer` function (`lme4` package) to get estimations in a Poisson regression model (generalized linear model).
I wanted to compare the estimations for the fixed effects with those obtained with the `glm` function.
I was surprised to see big differences !
 I know that `glmer` includes random effect; but that does not suffice to explain theses differences.

Could someone explain to me what I missed in my approach ?

**EDIT and ANSWER :**
Put an `offset` term in both `glm`and `glmer`

```
    library(surrosurv)
    library(survival)
    library(lme4)

     data(colon)
     colon1 = subset(colon, etype == 1)
    # Poissonization

   don_pois = poissonize(colon1, interval.width = 365.25, factors = c ('surg', 'rx'), compress = FALSE)
   names(don_pois)[3] = 'trt'; names(don_pois)[4] = 'trialref'


    fitpoi_glmer   <- glmer(
                    formula = event ~ -1 + interval + ( 1 | trialref ),
                    data = don_pois,
                    family = poisson(link = "log")
                     )


    fitpoi_glm <- glm(
      formula = event ~ -1+ interval + offset(log(time)), 
      data = don_pois, 
      family = poisson(link = "log")
    )


    summary(fitpoi_glmer)$coefficients 
    summary(fitpoi_glm)$coefficients

# Survival graphics

   fixed.coef.glmer = summary(fitpoi_glmer)$coefficients[,'Estimate']
     risks0 = exp(fixed.coef.glmer[grep("(?!.*:)interval.*", names(fixed.coef.glmer), perl = T)]) * 365.25
     surv0 <- c(1,exp(-cumsum(risks0)))
     x = seq(0, max(colon1$time), length.out = length(surv0))
     plot(x, surv0, type ='l', col = 'blue', lwd = 2)


     risks3 = exp(coef(fitpoi_glm)[grep("(?!.*:)interval.*", names(coef(fitpoi_glm)), perl = T)]) * 365.25
     surv3 <- c(1,exp(-cumsum(risks3)))
     lines(x, surv3, type ='l', col = 'pink', lwd = 2)

     # Comparison with survfit
     lines(survfit(Surv(time, status)~1, data = colon1 ), lty = 2, conf.int= FALSE)
```

Comment: What if you include the offset in `glmer`?

Comment: It seems you are right ! With adding the offset term, the two estimates are similar. Thanks a lot for your help, I was on this problem, my all day.

Comment: Glad I could help. You could answer your own question to "close" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent differences came from a simple oversight in the `glmer` formula.
We had to add an `offset` term!
I am editing the question.